# Can't seem to send more than 3 bytes from the NRF24L01+ TX to RX module

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, spi, embedded, nrf24l01

So I'm sending multiple payloads of the same width from the transmitter to a receiver and I see it sends only sends 3 times after which `TX_FULL` bit is set in the status register, and the receiver gets 3 payloads.

Note I'm using IRQ on the TX side and no IRQ on the RX side (just polling). Also, I'm not using auto-ack.

- What I don't get is how come TX fifo getting full at 3 bytes considering the tx fifo size is 32 bytes. I also checked `OBSERVE_TX` register and I see no lost bytes. Is this the reason behind not receiving more than 3 bytes?

Note that I checked `TX_FULL` in the status register as it reads `0x0f` while pushing to FIFO but as soon as I enable `CE` bit, I see the value reads `0x2E` indicating `TX_DS` is set, and IRQ is triggered.

- From what I have understood from the reference manual, you continue writing to the TX fifo but the transmission only begins after you enable the chip enable `(CE)` bit and after you enable `CE`, the data is sent in first-in-first-out order as opposed to sending each byte right away as it gets stored into the FIFO?

Following is what I did to transmit the payload: (for now I am polling despite using IRQ but eventually i'd be using callback functions to service the interrupt)

```
void send_payload(NRF *nrf, uint8_t *data, int len) {
    power_up();

    for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
        send_command(nrf, CMD_W_PAYLOAD, data[i], len); // populate the TX fifo with data
    }

    // enable transmission
    enable_chip_select();
   
    // wait till IRQ handler is done servicing
    while(nrf->state == NRF_TX_BUSY); 
    
    disable_chip_select(); 

}
```

[For reference](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/SMD/nRF24L01Pluss_Preliminary_Product_Specification_v1_0.pdf)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
        send_command(nrf, CMD_W_PAYLOAD, data[i], len); // populate the TX fifo with data
    }
```

It seems Tx FIFO is accessed beyond boundaries causing undefined behavior.